# C++, изменение диапазона распределителей

Tags: c++, числа

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему стандартные распределители случайных чисел не позволяют изменить диапазон распределения без пересоздания распределителей? Или же я просто не нашел описания методов, которые позволяют это сделать?

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution{ 0, 100 };
// Далее изменить диапазон уже невозможно?
```

Как именно устроены распределители? Является ли их пересоздание достаточно быстрой операцией?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

стандартные распределители случайных чисел  позволяют изменить диапазон распределения. Экземпляры имеют функции_члены, которые просто нужно использовать. Например:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution{ 0, 100 };
distribution.param(std::uniform_int_distribution<int>::param_type(8, 30));
```

теперь диапазон  изменился.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! А что насчет создания нового распределителя? Насколько быстро/медленно конструируется распределитель?

Comment: Это простой объект,  быстрота конструирования, не думаю, что уступает по быстроте  конструирования  таких же простых типов, как например std::complex